# Android Studio - Uri Upload to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, camera, uri

I'm trying to use the camera to take a picture and upload it to Firebase storage.  My app is connected to Firebase and passes the dependencies checks.  The code compiles fine and when I click on my button to open the camera, it opens the camera and lets me take a picture.  As soon as I'm done taking the picture and click okay to go back to the activity, it crashes the app.  I've tried several variations, and all seems to end the same way.  I have a front image, back image, and selfie, but I'm only working on the front image so that I can get it to work, then I'll add the back image and selfie picture.  I have the Firebase storage rules wide open so that anyone can write to it (this is a test environment with no real data).

Any thoughts on what would be crashing it?

```
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.j2objc.annotations.Weak;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

public class RegisterID extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    public String IDIssuer_Str = "Default";
    ActivityResultLauncher <Intent> activityResultLauncherfront;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_id);

        Spinner IDIssuerSpinner = findViewById(R.id.ID_Issuer_Spin);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ID_Issuer_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.ID_Issuer_List, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ID_Issuer_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        IDIssuerSpinner.setAdapter(ID_Issuer_adapter);
        IDIssuerSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Set variables for the front of the ID
        Button FrontIDImage_Btn = findViewById(R.id.IDFront_Btn);
        ImageView Front_Image_id = findViewById(R.id.IDFront_image);

        //Set variables for the back of the ID
        Button BackIDImage_Btn = findViewById(R.id.IDBack_Btn);
        ImageView Back_Image_id = findViewById(R.id.IDBack_image);

        //Set variables for a selfie button
        Button SelfieIDImage_Btn = findViewById(R.id.Selfie_Btn);
        ImageView Selfie_Image_id = findViewById(R.id.Selfie_image);

        //Set variables for a submit button
        Button SubmitFileToStorage = findViewById(R.id.Submit_IDs_Btn);

        //Actions when the Front ID Button is selected
        FrontIDImage_Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent front_ID_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                activityResultLauncherfront.launch(front_ID_intent);
            }
        });

        //Launch Camera for Front of ID camera picture
        activityResultLauncherfront = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    Bundle frontExtras = result.getData().getExtras();
                    Uri frontIDUri;
                    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) frontExtras.get("data");
                    Front_Image_id.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    WeakReference<Bitmap> FrontResult=new WeakReference<>(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
                            bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), false).copy
                            (Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true));

                    Bitmap FrontBM=FrontResult.get();
                    frontIDUri = saveFrontImage(FrontBM, RegisterID.this);

                    //Toast.makeText(RegisterID.this, (CharSequence) frontIDUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        SubmitFileToStorage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openSubmitIDtoStorage();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        switch(adapterView.getId()) {
            case (R.id.ID_Issuer_Spin):
                IDIssuer_Str = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
    }

    private Uri saveFrontImage(Bitmap FrontImage, Context context) {

        File imagesFolder=new File(context.getCacheDir(), "images");
        Uri uri=null;

        try {
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
            File file=new File (imagesFolder, "capture_Front_ID.jpg");
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            FrontImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
            uri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(context.getApplicationContext(), "com.project.MM"+".provider", file);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return uri;
    }

    public void openSubmitIDtoStorage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_Home.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Updated again with logcat info:

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5340)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5379)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:67)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2252)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
at com.mm.mm.RegisterID$2.onActivityResult(RegisterID.java:93)
at com.mm.mm.RegisterID$2.onActivityResult(RegisterID.java:78)
at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.doDispatch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:418)
at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.dispatchResult(ActivityResultRegistry.java:375)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:777)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8385)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5333)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5379) 
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:67) 
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2252) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

Comment: Yes, a NullPointerException. Please post the stacktrace fon the Logcat.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo - here's the logcat:

Comment: @AlexMamo - updated the issue with the logcat info.  I think it has to do with how I setup the provider?  In my AndroidManifest.xml I have: 
<provider
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths">
            </meta-data>
        </provider>

Comment: I think I fixed the provider issue.  Still crashing, but now logcat is saying:

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting the error now?

Comment: The code still compiles just fine.  I think this is my issue - java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence. I'm not exactly sure where that is tied to, but looking now.

Comment: @AlexMamo - I am a bit of a novice (as I'm sure you can already tell).  I'm not really sure how to read the logcat to pinpoint the issue.  I think it's related to data types (char, file, etc...) but not sure how to find the lines of code that it's related to from the logcat data.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - the provider issue was the real issue.  Once I fixed that, the CharSequence issue was a make.toast issue that I created myself to try and troubleshoot the provider issue.  So once I fixed both, no more crashes.  It's still not writing the image file to Firebase, but that's for another thread if I can't get it working on my own.